# apt-get not working behind socks proxy

Tags: apt

I am trying to connect a Ubuntu 12.04 machine to a socks proxy server. I have my  `192.168.30.0/24` LAN, and dante socks proxy server is running on `192.168.30.134:1018`. I have also a `pfsense` router on `192.168.30.31` which creates a inferior LAN `192.168.1.0/24`.

In this inferior LAN, I have an Ubuntu client machine and I need to connect it to my proxy server, so that all traffic on this machine is proxied. I have configured socks proxy in global ubuntu settings. `pfsense` firewall is configured to allow direct connection from LANtoWAN only to my socks proxy server (and also my local DNS and Google DNS).

All other traffic is blocked (because it should go through my proxy server). Browsing is working OK so I know It is configured right and going through proxy, but I cannot get `apt-get update` and etc. commands working. I was trying to configure `proxychains` or `dante-client` to run it with `proxychains` or `socksify` prefix but it doesn't work. `socksify` gives no result, and `proxychains` just give me `failed to fetch http:// ....... Connection failed` type of errors when I run it as a root.

How can I get `apt-get` working? Is it possible to manage it without any third party (dante-client, proxychains, etc.) client?

Comment: Another sad example for users downvoting and closevoting of things they don't understand.

Comment: @LiveWireBT I agree. I don't see why a downvote is at place here. This is a well explained and well researched question.

Comment: Your router creates network 192.168.1.0/24 that means giving out addresses `192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254` so why have you given 192.168.30.x to your servers?

Answer (score 1):

In order for apt to work behind proxy, you need to set it in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. Create this file and write the following to it:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@host:port_no/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@host:port_no/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@host:port_no/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://username:password@host:port_no/";
```

Replacing username by *your username* and password by *your password*(if applicable) and host and port_no by *the host of proxy* and *port no of your proxy*.

Comment: Tried but same output. Should I set also http, https and ftp in apt.conf? because I have only socks proxy server running, and I am not sure whether it can be accesed as http, https or ftp proxy.

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: Well i tried it that way, but as i said, same output.