# Is SOCKS4/5 supported by apt?

Tags: apt, socks5

The [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt.conf) for `apt.conf` doesn't mention SOCKS at all. Yet there are [a few questions](https://askubuntu.com/q/35223/158442) [about SOCKS](https://askubuntu.com/q/401419/158442) [and apt](https://askubuntu.com/q/519567/158442) here, and every now and then I see an answer which has something like:

```
Acquire::http::proxy ..
Acquire::https::proxy ..
Acquire::ftp::proxy ..
Acquire::socks::proxy ..
```

(all four) in them. `Acquire::socks` doesn't raise an error, but doesn't seem to have an effect either.

What exactly is the state of support for SOCKS proxies in `apt`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [syntax for SOCKS proxy in apt.conf](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35223/syntax-for-socks-proxy-in-apt-conf)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen if you notice, that is one of the questions I have linked to. I don't feel it answers my question as stated. If you do, please explain how.

Comment: There are two options in the answers of that question. If you are having a problem you need to update your question and provide sufficient information for us to help you. We need information on your socks proxy (what proxy you are using), how the socks proxy is configured, and what you have done to configure apt. Did you even try tsocks ? Post your configuration files. Version of Ubuntu also helps.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I am not using a socks proxy. I am not having a problem with socks. I am asking if apt supports SOCKS directly, and if it doesn't, does `Acquire::socks` have any meaning at all? Answers for any and all currently supported versions of Ubuntu are welcome. I am not going to try tsocks, because that's working around apt, not with it. There's nothing to more post. The question is self-contained, and please read a bit more carefully.

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. This is the sort of question that needs to remain open, because somebody could come along any time in the future with a correction and at that time it would be useful for the community to have documentation that `Acquire::socks` _does_ exist, where there is a definitive record of it and where to find out more information about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The apt source code has no mention of SOCKS whatsoever:

```
/tmp/apt-1.0.9.1ubuntu1$ grep -ir socks .
/tmp/apt-1.0.9.1ubuntu1$
```

It's also possible to have extension plugins for apt, such as `apt-transport-https`. These add files to `/usr/lib/apt/methods/`. So I used `apt-file find` to look for any other packages that provide files into this directory. This also did not reveal anything SOCKS related.

It's impossible to prove a negative, but I'd say that it's safe to say that apt itself has no SOCKS support right now. It looks like tsocks is the only real way forward.

I'm confused as to how others have concluded that `Acquire::socks` exists, but I can find no evidence of it. If I've missed something then I guess this answer is completely wrong (and I'll delete it).

Comment: Does DOT(.) at the end of first command is important?

Comment: "If I've missed something..." - that's why I posted this question. If you set a SOCKS proxy using the network settings, and apply it system wide, an `Acquire::socks` line is added to `/etc/apt/apt/conf`. I was pretty sure I missed something.

Comment: @KasiyA yes, he's grepping recursively through the current directory (`.`). Otherwise it will wait for input on stdin.

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct anymore. The [source code](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/1.6.2) of apt `1.6.2`, (which is part of Ubuntu 18.04) does have many occurrences of `socks` when you grep for that word via `grep -ir socks .` - therefore it seems there is at least some support for socks within `apt` now.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested Acquire::http::proxy which works fine (or not if the proxy is down), but :socks: just goes directly to the net, skipping any (absent or not) proxy.

So it would seem it's impossible to use apt over socks, at least on Ubuntu 16.04.2.